# Adding subcategories to laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have categories table in my application and it works just fine but i wonder how to get subcategories for that as well?

currently what I have is:

Category Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

  protected $fillable = ['name'];

  public function ads(){
     return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
  }

}
```

Category Migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My Post Model:

```
public function category(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

PS: I know I have to make new table and call for foreign key of `category_id` for subcategories but what makes me confuse is the relationships and also how to select them in front-end so category and subcategories all shows in one drop down to user (like WP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i really don't understand well what you're trying to do .. but if you're trying to add both categories and subcategories in one dropdown i assume this is what you wanted:

let's say you already have done the relationship .. in your controller

```
$categories = Category::with('sub_categories')->get();
return view('page',compact('categories'));
```

now we got all the categories and it's corresponding sub-categories .. in your blade all you have to do is

```
<select name="categories">
@foreach($categories as $categ)
    <optgroup label="{{ $categ->name }}">
        @foreach($categ->sub_categories as $sub)
            <option value="{{ $sub->id }}">{{ $sub->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </optgroup>
@endforeach
</select>
```

> and that would give you an output like

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Fruits">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Banana</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Vegetables">
    <option value="3">Beans</option>
    <option value="4">Cabbage</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

relationship is easy as understanding english .. actually you've done it already in your category ads ..

**CATEGORY MODEL**

```
public function ads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ad');
    // return $this->hasMany('App\Ad','theforeignfieldtocomparetomyprimarykey')
}
```

`hasMany` - this means Ad model has `category_id` in it's database table as field ..

in your **AD MODEL**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    // return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','myfieldtocompare');
}
```

`belongsTo` - since the function name is `category` it will look up on his fields for `category_id` and match it to the `primary key` of `model category`

so basically what you have to do is first make models with migrations like:

**CATEGORY**

- id
- name

**SUB CATEGORY**

- id
- category_id
- name

then in your model you should have a script as exampled above ..

Comment: `let's say you already have done the relationship .. in your controller` as I said `what makes me confuse is the relationships` .

Comment: Hi man, I made it it works but how to add subcategories in selected category from front-end? now i can get the list of cats & subs but for connect them to each other and save it?

Comment: let's go in our discussion

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145403/discussion-between-sagar-and-robert-nicjoo