# Laravel not return subcategories result

Tags: php, laravel, search

I added subcategories to my app with help of here [Adding subcategories to laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251433/adding-subcategories-to-laravel-5-4) and before that my search base on `category` worked just fine now i try to change my search base on `subcategory` and it doesn't return results.

here is my search function:

```
 public function search()
{
    $searchTitle = request('title');
    $searchCategory = request('subcategory');
    $searchLocation = request('location');

    $ads = null;

    if($searchTitle || $searchCategory || $searchLocation) {
        $ads = Ad::when($searchTitle, function ($query) use ($searchTitle) {
                return $query->where('title', 'like', "%{$searchTitle}%")
                    ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$searchTitle}%");
            })
            ->when($searchCategory, function ($query) use ($searchCategory) {
                return $query->whereHas('subcategory', function ($query) use ($searchCategory) {
                    $query->where('id', $searchCategory);
                });
            })
            ->when($searchLocation, function ($query) use ($searchLocation) {
                return $query->whereHas('location', function ($query) use ($searchLocation) {
                    $query->where('id', $searchLocation);
                });
            })
            ->paginate(10)
            ->appends(request()->query());
    }

    return view('search-result', compact('ads'));
}
```

this is my search form category part:

```
<label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select category" class="sr-only mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Category</label>
              <select name="subcategory_id" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select category"
                      class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                      <option value="">Select category</option>
                      @foreach ($categories as $category)
                        <optgroup label="{{ $category->name }}">
                          @foreach($category->subcategories as $sub)
                              <option value="{{ $sub->id }}">{{ $sub->name }}</option>
                          @endforeach
                        </optgroup>
                      @endforeach
              </select>
```

I tried many changes and played with mu function code but nothing still will return `no results!` error.

Comment: Have you tried dd to know what you are getting from that query ??

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu no where should i put dd() and with what attribute?!

Comment: remove paginate and try dd($ads) .

Comment: return.. `null`

Comment: remove appends and again use dd .

Comment: return `no results!`

Comment: then check your queries

Comment: hello there kido .. have you tried to check the value of those variables ?

Comment: hello @Demonyowh no :)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145408/discussion-between-robert-nicjoo-and-demonyowh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should probably work

```
$ads = Ad::when($searchTitle, function ($query) use ($searchTitle) {
    return $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$searchTitle.'%')
        ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$searchTitle.'%');
})
->when($searchCategory, function ($query) use ($searchCategory) {
    return $query->whereHas('subcategory', function ($q) use ($searchCategory) {
        $q->where('id', $searchCategory);
    });
})
->when($searchLocation, function ($query) use ($searchLocation) {
    return $query->whereHas('location', function ($q) use ($searchLocation) {
        $q->where('id', $searchLocation);
    });
})
->paginate(10)
->appends(request()->query());
```

> also don't forget the names of your inputs .. it should be as corresponding to the request ..